# what is the Widget get _appBar meaning in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am reading a flutter code like this:

```
  Widget get _appBar {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0x66000000), Colors.transparent],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 20, 0, 0),
            height: 86.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:
                    Color.fromARGB((appBarAlpha * 255).toInt(), 255, 255, 255),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: appBarAlpha == 1.0
                        ? Colors.black12
                        : Colors.transparent,
                    offset: Offset(2, 3),
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    spreadRadius: 0.6,
                  ),
                ]),
            child: SearchBar(
              searchBarType: appBarAlpha > 0.2
                  ? SearchBarType.homeLight
                  : SearchBarType.home,
              inputBoxClick: _jumpToSearch,
              defaultText: SEARCH_BAR_DEFAULT_TEXT,
              leftButtonClick: () {},
              speakClick: _jumpToSpeak,
              rightButtonClick: _jumpToUser,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            height: appBarAlpha > 0.2 ? 0.5 : 0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 0.5)]))
      ],
    );
  }
```

what is the meaning of `Widget get _appBar`? is it get a appBar control? why not return a AppBar directly?

Comment: Did you run the full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "getter":

> Getters and setters are special methods that provide read and write access to an object’s properties. Recall that each instance variable has an implicit getter, plus a setter if appropriate. You can create additional properties by implementing getters and setters, using the get and set keywords

([Dart Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters))

So `Widget get _appBar` is a getter for a property called `_appBar` that is of type `Widget`. You could have just made it a function: `Widget _appBar()`.

I guess your code uses this app bar in multiple places and so has found a way to put the code in one place to call it from all the other places instead of duplicating all of it.

Answer (score 3):

The `get` keyword is used in dart code to provide read access to an object's property. Often this is done with methods (like your case). *[Check this out for more on `getters` and `setters`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters)*. In `Widget get _appBar` we see the `Widget` return type, the `get` keyword (indicating it's a getter) and the name of the field/getter - `_appBar`.

In this example, a field getter `_appBar` is defined as an interface for returning a widget. Getters can *sort of* disguise a method as a field. so the way you'll access this field looks like this:

```dart
var someObject = SomeObject();

// here we're accessing the field and assigning it to a different object
var widget = someObject._appBar;
```

Now there is some interesting things going on here with the name of the getter. It starts with an underscore (`_`), indicating it's a private member. This could be intentional for only the library/package/class's use internally - rather than accessing it in another location.

Likely that the code isn't returning an `AppBar` directly is because this is a custom implementation for an app bar. You don't need to provide an `AppBar` widget to a `Scaffold`'s `appBar` parameter, you only need to provide a `PreferredSizeWidget` to the parameter. Check out the docs on it [here (*`Scaffold`*)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html), [here (*`appBar` property*)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/appBar.html), and [here(*`PreferredSizeWidget`*)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html).